# ListView Load More when Scroll Up

Tags: android, android-listview, onscrolllistener

Does anyone know how to create a scroll listener that has this functionality:

- List View: scroll to top and reach on first item then load more called. (Means load more on Scroll Up)

I set `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` in xml.

Comment: you can add header and `setOnClickListener`.. than load more data on its `onClick() `

Comment: Actually i set android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" so when i am gonna  add some item in ArrayList then listview scrolls at bottom so How can i achieve above funtionality?

Comment: Do you implement this functionality? 
When i update my adapter listView scrolled to up and doesn't save scroll position before load more

Answer (score 4):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    /
    if (firstVisibleItem ==0) {
        loadmore();//your load more function
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Also should add new items to begin of list in adapter